# Stripping every and all emoji from a sentence string

Tags: python, unicode, emoji

Working environment Python version:

```
Python 3.6.1
```

I've tried a number of methods outlined here on StackOverflow and other places around the internet - yet I still can't seem to get this working.

I could have any string...and the emojis may or may not be surrounded by whitespace, may be within " or after a hashtag etc etc...anyways, these circumstances are giving me some troubles.

This is what I have:

```
import sys
sys.maxunicode

emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
                           u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  
                           u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"
                           u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"
                           u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"
                           "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)

text = "" #This could be any text with or without emojis
text = emoji_pattern.sub(r'', text)
```

The above however when displayed or printed still have the emojis within the text.

`text` is a unicode string i.e., `type(text)` returns `<type 'unicode'>`

So what am I missing? I seem to have emojis remaining. I would also prefer a method that reflects that these Unicode designations could be expanded upon in the future so I would rather just have a method that keeps all regular characters.

Encoding the text as `'unicode_escape'` gives the following:

```
b'[1/2] Can you see yourself as Prompto or Aranea?\\nGet higher quality images from our FB page \\n\\u2b07\\ufe0f\\u2026'
```

The raw unformatted text is:

```
[1/2] Can you see yourself as Prompto or Aranea?
Get higher quality images from our FB page
⬇️…
```

Comment: Are you sure you're on Python 3? On Python 3, `type(text)` should return `str`.

Comment: Your regex seems to be using UTF-16 surrogates rather than the actual code points of the characters you want to remove.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Hi Alistair - you're correct. I wasn't in the correct environment - just activated and I actually get `<Class 'str'>` ...that being said, in the Python 3.6 env I still return the text with the emojis.

Comment: @user2357112 Ok - just quickly checked this, and amended to include sys.maxunicode and changed the emoji_pattern to reference.

Comment: That is a byte string with literal escape codes.  `.decode('unicode-escape')` to get a Unicode string. 
 Those characters are not in the ranges you've specified, however.  I thought Twitter returned JSON, so you might want to look at the `json` module for processing it.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I don't need to decode it as it already is unicode (i.e., will receive a `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` error)...I used `.encode('unicode-escape')` to see what was under the hood. How else could I know which unicode ranges/emoji formats are being used and how many possible ranges are there?

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/index.html

Comment: @MarkTolonen Wouldn't even know where to begin with all those lists and different formats. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you think `sys.maxunicode` does, but your code works with Python 3.6.  Are you sure you have all the emoji ranges covered?

```
import re

emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
                           u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  
                           u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"
                           u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"
                           u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"
                           "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)

text = 'Actual text with emoji: ->\U0001F620\U0001F310\U0001F690\U0001F1F0<-'
print(text)
text = emoji_pattern.sub(r'', text)
print(text)
```

Output:

```
Actual text with emoji: -><-
Actual text with emoji: -><-
```

Note that `flags=re.UNICODE` is the default in Python 3.6, so it is not needed.  Unicode strings are also the default, so `u"xxxx"` can just be `"xxxx"`.

Comment: @Michael Roberts Then provide a [minimal, correct, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with an actual text string that fails for you instead of `text = "" #This could be any text with or without emojis`.  We aren't mind readers.  You don't have to provide the code that retrieves the data from Twitter, but the text string as you receive it.  It may be a byte string or JSON-encoded or something.

Comment: Added the text example I have in both raw format and encoded unicode escape format. Hopefully someone will know what to do with it.